# Indexing my dataframe properly with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to plot a bargraph with errorbars acquired from my tests, i found some code on the internet on how to make it. But the code does not fit the way i want the table to look like.

I've tried leaving things out however i don't understand the dataframe enough to know what kind of code i need to process the data correctly.

```py
order=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['402515','402515','402515','402510','402510','402510'],
                                 ['z','z','z','z','z','z']],names=['letter','word'])
datas=pd.DataFrame({'first cracking strength':[em1,em2,em3,em4,em5,em6],'flexural strength':[en1,en2,en3,en4,en5,en6]},index=order)
gp4 = datas.groupby(level=('letter', 'word'))
means = gp4.mean()
errors = gp4.std()
print(means)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
means.plot.bar(yerr=errors, ax=ax, capsize=4);
```

The multi-index code requires two labels (the `'z'` and the `'402515/402510'`, I only want the `'402515/402510'`) on your dataset, but I only want one. What other code does that?

How it looks when I run the code.

[image: img]

How I want it to look.

[image: intended]

Comment: have you tried `droplevel` ? ie `means.droplevel('word').plot.bar(yerr=errors.droplevel('word'), ax=ax, capsize=4)`  this method only exists with versions `0.24.0` or higher

Comment: No i didn't, but it works perfect! Thank you!